# Can I Create a SQL Table Like this With to tables connectin to one?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
Create Table Movie (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Title varchar(50),
    ReleaseDate date not null,
    Genre varchar(50),
    Price decimal(18,2),
    Rating varchar(50),
    Autors_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie_Autors(Autors_ID)
)

Create Table Autors (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(50),
    Born date not null,
    About text,
    Movie_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie_Autors(Movie_ID)
)

Create Table Movie_Autors (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Movie_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(ID),
    Autors_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Autors(ID),
)
```

Comment: No.  If you try, you'll get an error on `Movies` because `Move_Autors` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes it is a many to many table structure, looks like you already have it done.  Except for clarity maybe name the ID in Authors and Movie the same as in the Movie_Authors table so MovieID  in both tables is the ID

Comment: Actually, having looked deeper - why do you have `Autors_Id` and `Movie_Id` columns in the `Autors` and `Movie` tables? The many-to-many link between the two tables is maintained in the `Movie_Autors` table.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have the Foreign Key going both directions. Only the table Movie_Autors should have the foreign key to Movie, Autors table.

Comment: Also consider not having an identity on the Movie_Autors table and instead make Movie_ID and Autors_ID a compound PK.  This will ensure you can not have multiple links between the same movie and autor.  And did you really mean autor and not author?

Comment: @juharr, i would have the Movie_ID and Authors_ID as unique constraint and keep the ID. I think it's easier to manage the records when you have an ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, this is what you want:

```
Create Table Movie (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Title varchar(50),
    ReleaseDate date not null,
    Genre varchar(50),
    Price decimal(18,2),
    Rating varchar(50)
);

Create Table Autors (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(50),
    Born date not null,
    About varchar(max)
);

Create Table Movie_Autors (
    ID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    Movie_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(ID),
    Autors_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Autors(ID),
);
```

That is, you have no foreign key references in `Movies` or `Autors`, so you should not declare any.

As a note `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY` are redundant.  `PRIMARY KEY` is sufficient.

I also changed `text` to `varchar(max)`.  [The `text` datatype has been deprecated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)